# Android ListView empties when swiping through ViewPager couple of times

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a ViewPager with 3 tabs.

First tab loads contacts into ListView, which extends ListFragment.

`onCreate`, I `Asynchronously` load contact list into `ArrayList`, then on task's post execute method, I load it into adapter by `setListAdapter(new CustomContactListViewAdapter(getActivity(), contactList);` Everything works as expected, but when I swipe through the ViewPager couple of times, and then come back to the Fragment/Page, the list is empty.

Are there any known bugs/workarounds to this?

I am willing to post my code, just don't know which part will be helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Adding some code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  ViewPager mViewPager;
  TabAdapter mAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }

  public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { super(fm); }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch(index) {
          case 0:
            return ContactFragment();
          case 1:
            return SecondFragment();
          case 2:
            return ThirdFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post code of that?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan which part, the fragment, main activity or tab adapter?

Comment: first please post fragment class

Comment: Are you setting anything for your ViewPager's offScreenPageLimit()?  Are you using a FragmentPagerAdapter or a FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: @JDJ FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Not using offScreenPageLimit().

Comment: Have you considered using a FragmentPagerAdapter so the pages are cached and not destoyed like they are in a FragmentStatePagerAdapter?  It may be that the fragment that your were trying to update isn't around anymore when the AsyncTask hits onPostExecute.

Comment: I was using FragmentPagerAdapter first, then decided to give FragmentStatePagerAdapter a try. No dice.

Comment: Since there are only 3 tabs, you can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead, and call `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`. This way it will keep the fragment in the memory and will not create it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Pr38y

Since there are only 3 tabs, you can use FragmentPagerAdapter instead, and call pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);. This way it will keep the fragment in the memory and will not create it again.